# Jcombobox value change while clicking on jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jtable, full-text-search, jcombobox

I have to search contents of a jtable using values of two relative jcomboboxes.But when i click on the search jbutton, it's not working,although the value in one jcombobox is changed.. how to overcome this problem

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Post your code, otherwise we can't help you. What it means it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two `jComboBox`:

```
jComboBox1 and jComboBox2
```

now I store selected two values from `jComboBoxes` as `String` and made action event in your `jButton` like:

```
String str1=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String str2=jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();    

searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                searchValue(sre1,str2);
            }
    });

public void searchValue(String str1, String str2){
    //your code to get connection and so on
    try{

        /**
        *You can make your select query like:
        *SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE someField1='"+str1+"' and someField2='"+str2+"'
        */

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```